# servidor lighttpd no carga script .js

Tags: javascript, linux, debian, lighttpd

tengo una pagina con un main.js dentro
cuando la veo por localhost carga
cuando la veo por 127.0.01 o por la ip 192.168.6 que la ip propia no carga el script

el servidor el lighttpd ver lighttpd/1.4.55 (ssl)

esta corriendo en un debia 10

Comment: ¿Qué puerto estás usando? Es probable que debas especificarlo en el navegador, ejemplo, para el puerto 8080: `http://192.168.6.1:8080`

Comment: el puerto es el 80